# Quotient Topology $X / \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset X$. We can define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $x_1 \sim x_2$ if $x_1 = x_2$ or if both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in $A.$ Then we can naturally define the quotient topology $X/A$ on the set of all the equivalence classes generated by the equivalence relation $\sim$. My question is this: if $A = \emptyset$, then why is $\emptyset$ also an equivalence class? By definition, equivalence classes are generated by a point in the set $X$, i.e., for some $a \in X$, we have $[a]:= \{x \in X \ | \ a \sim x\}$. But what element generates the empty set?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think $\emptyset$ is an equivalence class?

Comment: What in the above suggests $A$ is always an equivalence class? It clearly is when $A$ is non-empty, but, as you say…

Comment: Actually, the relation $\sim$ used for $X/A$ is not as you describe.  It is: $x_1 \sim x_2$ iff either $x_1=x_2$ or both $x_1, x_2$ are in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you seem to think that $A$ is always an equivalence class in this scenario. Which is true if $A\neq\emptyset$, otherwise it is false. For the empty set $X/\emptyset=\big\{\{x\}\ |\ x\in X\big\}$ is pretty much the same as $X$. Every equivalence class is a singleton. Which you can check yourself by realizng that "or $x_1, x_2\in A$" condition can never be satisfied when $A=\emptyset$.

So: why is $\emptyset$ also an equivalence class? The answer is: it is not.

Also note that hardly anyone considers $X/\emptyset$ quotient. So if you read somewhere that $A$ is an equivalence class, then it is likely that $A$ was assumed to be nonempty to begin with.

Comment: I slightly disagree that hardly anyone considers the quotient $X/\emptyset$. For instance, in the cellular boundary formula in the case $n=0$ it is useful to consider said quotient to see that the first differential of a cellular chain complex is zero if the CW-complex has precisely one $0$-cell. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572229/in-cellular-homology-how-should-we-define-the-degree-of-a-map-between-0-spher) for instance.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you define quotient. Quotient are also defined categorically as adjunction spaces. $X/A$ is the pushout of two maps from $A$. The first map is the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$. The second map is the unique map to a point $A \rightarrow p$. With this definition, we get the counter-intuitive result that $A/\emptyset$ is $A$ together with an additional point. If you take the platonic view of mathematical objects, then this may simply be an artefact of this definition. A description of adjunctions spaces can be found here: [https://math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/pushout.pdf](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Ejmb/note/pushout.pdf)