# Isomorphism between cellular and simplicial chain complexes for a triangulable space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given a triangulable space $X$, by definition there exists an homeomorphism $F:|K|\to X$, where $|K|$ is the support of a simplicial complex. It's easy to see that $X$ inherits a natural structure of CW-complex. Now, I have some problems with the proof my professor gave us of the fact that for all $q\in\mathbb Z$: $$H_q^\Delta(K)\cong H_q^{CW}(X)$$
The proof is the following.

Let fix an orientation on the vertices of $K$, such that every simplex of $K$ inherits an orientation. It is clear that for every $\tau=\langle P_0,\ldots,P_q\rangle\in K^q$ (here $K^q$ is the $q$-skeleton of $K$) there exists an affine map $\hat\tau:\Delta_q:=\langle e_0,\ldots,e_q\rangle\to K$ such that $\hat\tau(e_i)=P_i$ for every $i=0,\ldots,q$. This allows us to define: $$\Phi^q_\tau:\mathbb D^q\xrightarrow{\psi_q}\Delta_q\xrightarrow{\hat\tau}K\xrightarrow{F}X$$
where $\mathbb D^q$ is the closed $q$-dimensional disk and $\psi_q$ is an homeomorphism between $\mathbb D^q$ and the standard $q$-simplex $\Delta_q$. Thus for every $q$ we can consider $$X^q:=\bigcup_{q'\leq q\\\tau\in K^{q'}}\Phi^{q'}_\tau(\mathbb D^{q'})$$ which can be proved to be the $q$-skeleton of the CW-complex structure induced on $X$. At this point any $\tau\in K^q$ induces the map $F_*\tau:=F\circ\hat\tau:\Delta_q\to X^q$, which is an element of $S_q(X^q)$, where $S_q(X^q)$ is the free module generated by the singular $q$-simplices. So for every $q\in\mathbb Z$ it's possible to define $u_q:C_q(K)\to S_q^{CW}(X):=H_q(X^q,X^{q-1})$ in the following way:
$$u_q:\langle\tau\rangle\in C_q(K)\to F_*\tau\in S_q(X^q)\xrightarrow{j_q}j_q(F_*\tau)\in S_q(X^q,X^{q-1})\to [j_q(F_*\tau)]\in H_q(X^q,X^{q-1})=:S_q^{CW}(X)$$

It's briefly said that all the $u_q$ are clearly isomorphisms of modules, but I don't see why (and this is my first problem with the proof). Now, given that for true, if we prove that the following diagram commutes $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C_q(K) @>{u_q}>> S_q^{CW}(X)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
C_{q-1}(K) @>{u_{q-1}}>> S_{q-1}^{CW}(X)
\end{CD} we are done, beacuse we have an isomorphism at a chain level, which, thanks to the functoriality of homology, induces an isomorphism in homology. Now:
$$\begin{align*}&u_{q-1}(\partial \tau)=[j_{q-1}(F_*\hat{\partial\tau})]=[j_{q-1}\partial(F_*\hat\tau)]\\&d_q(u_q(\tau))=d_q[j_q(F_*\hat\tau)]=j_{q-1}(\partial_*)_q[j_q(F_*\hat\tau)]\end{align*}$$ where the $j_{q-1}$ outside the squared parenthesis is the morphism that goes from $H_{q-1}(X^{q-1})$ to $H_{q-1}(X^{q-1},X^{q-2})$ and $(\partial_*)_q:H_q(X^q,X^{q-1})\to H_{q-1}(X^{q-1})$.

I would be very glad if someone could explain me the reasons why the $u_q$'s are isomorphisms and the diagram written above commute, because I can't see them. I appreciate your help and I thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
I'm adding some further details. As specified in the comments, given a CW-complex $X$, we used the fact that $\frac{X^j}{X^{j-1}}\cong \bigvee_{\alpha\in A_j}S^j_\alpha$ in order to define the modules of the cellular chain complex as: $$S_q^{CW}(X):=H_q^{\text{sing}}(X^q,X^{q-1})\cong\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A_q} \tilde H_q(S^q_\alpha)=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A_q}R\cdot[e^q_\alpha]$$ where $R$ is the ring of the coefficients and $e^q_\alpha$ a $q$-cell. At this point the differentials $d_q:S_q^{CW}(X)\to S_{q-1}^{CW}(X)$ are the ones induced by the following diagram:
[image]

Comment: Its hard for me to follow this proof. What exactly $S_q^{CW}$ is? Is it supposed to be cellular chain complex? Then $S_q^{CW}(X)=H_q(X^q, X^{q-1})$ is confusing, this isn't homology. Also, why do you mention singular simplices? Singular homology isn't related to all of this, no?

Comment: @freakish You can define the cellular chain complex via $C_n^{\mathrm{CW}}(X) = H_n^{\mathrm{Sing}}(X^n, X^{n-1})$ and the differential the boundary operator of the LES of the triple $(X^n, X^{n-1}, X^{n-2})$. But I find it really weird that cellular homology is defined in this way and then simplicial homology is defined as the free abelian group on simplices.

Comment: @VincentBoelens oh, wow, that's the first time I've heard about it. But then isn't $H_n(X^n, X^{n-1})$ not necessarily free? I mean such complexes don't have to be isomorphic, or am I missing something?

Comment: @freakish It is free, at least for singular homology. By excision and additivity the characteristic maps yield an isomorphism $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A}H_\ast(D^n_\alpha, S^{n-1}_\alpha)\cong H_\ast (X^n, X^{n-1})$. Alternatively, $X^{n-1}\to X^n$ is a cofibration, hence $H_\ast(X^n,X^{n-1})\cong H_\ast(X^n/X^{n-1},\ast) = H_\ast(\bigvee_{\alpha\in A}S^n_\alpha,\ast)$. This works for any additive theory, not just singular homology.

Comment: The formula for $d_q(u_q(\tau))$ is wrong. If $\sigma\in S_q(X^q,X^{q-1})$ is a cycle, then $\partial_q([\sigma]) = d\tau$, where $\tau\in S_q(X^q)$ such that $j_q(\tau) = \sigma$. In particular $\partial_q([j_q\sigma]) = [d\sigma]$, hence $d^\mathrm{CW}_q(u_q(\tau)) = [j_{q-1}(dF_\ast \tau)]$. From this you immediately see that the $u_q$ form a chain map.

Comment: @VincentBoelens My bad, it was easier than I tought to prove that the $u_q$ form a chain map. But... Why are they isomorphisms? Thank you for your help, in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write in your question the $q$-cells of $X$ correspond bijectively to the $q$-simplices of $K$ and for $\tau$ a $q$-simplex the $q$-cell $e_\tau^q$
is has characteristic map $\Phi^q_\tau$.
Consider the composite
$$C_q(K)\xrightarrow{u_q} H_q(X^q, X^{q-1})\xrightarrow{\cong} H_q(X^q/X^{q-1},\ast) = \tilde{H}_q(X^q/X^{q-1}).$$
A careful check shows that $\tau\in C_q(K)$ is mapped to the singular simplex
$$\Delta^q\xrightarrow{\hat\tau} K^q\xrightarrow{F} X^q\to X^q/X^{q-1},$$
which is exactly the basis element of $\tilde H_q(X^q/X^{q-1})$ corresponding to $e_\tau^q$. Thus, $u_q$ maps basis elements bijectively, hence is an isomorphism.

Comment: Now it's so much clearer. Thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram in your question is taken from Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", thus I think you are familiar with this book.

The definition of cellular homology homology groups is based on the celluar chain complex $S^{CW}_*(X)$ described in your question. However, Hatcher gives an alternative description as follows:

Take ${\bar S}^{CW}_n(X)  =$ free abelian group generated by the $n$-cells of $X$. The boundary maps $d_n : {\bar S}^{CW}_n(X) \to {\bar S}^{CW}_{n-1}(X)$ are specified on p. 140. For $n=1$ it agrees with
the simplicial boundary map $Δ_1(X) \to Δ_0(X)$. See [First differential in cellular homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4592783). For $n > 1$ one has the **Cellular Boundary Formula**. You can also use this formula for $n = 1$; see [In cellular homology, how should we define the degree of a map between $0$-spheres?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572229)

The chain complexes ${\bar S}^{CW}_*(X)$ and $S^{CW}_*(X)$ are canonically isomorphic, thus they produce identical homology groups. The benefit of ${\bar S}^{CW}_*(X)$ is that it does not use the singular homology groups of the pairs $(X^n,X^{n-1})$. However, for practical computations we need the boundary maps - in other words, we must determine the degrees of certain  maps between spheres. In general this may be difficult. And here we need again singular homology: The degree of map $f : S^n \to S^n$ is introduced via $f_* : H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n)$ (see Hatcher p.134).

In case that $X = \lvert K \rvert$ we have a very nice CW-structure on $X$ and can easily determine the required degrees. Try it!

With this knowledge it is fairly obvious that there is a canonical isomorphism of chain complexes
$$C_*(K) \to {\bar S}^{CW}_n(X) .$$

The purpose of all this is to prove the topological invariance of the simplicial homology of a triangulable space $X$. We can choose any triangulation $F : \lvert K \rvert \to X$ and compute $H^{\Delta}_*(K)$. We know that $H^{\Delta}_*(K) \approx H^{CW}_*(\lvert K \rvert)$. By Hatcher's Theorem 2.35 we know that $H^{CW}_*(\lvert K \rvert) \approx H_*(\lvert K \rvert) \approx H_*(X)$.