# Hatcher example 3b.3

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, alternative-proof

In Hatcher example 3B.3, we calculate the homology of $X\times S^k$. I know there is a solution by Kunneth formula
$$
H_n(X\times S^k)\cong \bigoplus\limits_{n=r+s}H_r(X)\otimes_\mathbb Z H_s(S^k)
$$
where this boils down to $H_n(X)\oplus H_{n-k}(X)$ by property of the tensor product and homology. Hatcher seems to calculate the homology by looking at the chain complex, as follows:

> The boundary formula in $C_*(X\times S^k)$ takes the form $d(a\times b) = da\times b$ since $d = 0$ in $C_*(S^k)$. *Therefore, the chain complex $C_*(X\times S^k)$ is just the direct sum of two copies of the chain complex $C_*(X)$, one of the copies having its dimension shifted upwards by $k$.* Therefore, $H_n(X\times S^k)\cong H_n(X)\oplus H_{n-k}(X)$.

Can anyone explain the italic part, where we obtain a direct sum of the chain complexes with some index shifting? It is unclear to me how this part was done. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatcher works with the cellular homology groups of CW-complexes. In Proposition 3B.1. he proves that the boundary map in the cellular chain complex $C_*(X×Y)$ is determined by the boundary maps in the cellular chain complexes $C_∗(X)$ and $C_∗(Y)$ via the formula $d(e_i×e_j) = de_i×e_j + (−1)^ie_i×de_j$.

Now consider $Y = S^k$ with the standard CW-structure (one $0$-cell $b^0$ and one $k$-cell $b^k$). Then $d = 0$ in $C_*(S^k)$. This is trivial for $k \ne 1$. For $k = 1$ we enconter a little problem because the cellular boundary formula (see p.140) requires to determine the degree of a map $S^0 \to S^0$. For the answer see [In cellular homology, how should we define the degree of a map between $0$-spheres?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572229) It shows that $d=0$ also in this case.

Therefore $d(a \times b) = da \times b$ for the cells of $X \times S^k$.

The $n$-cells of $X \times S^k$ are the products $a \times b$ of all cells $a$ of $X$ and $b$ of $S^k$ such that $\dim a + \dim b = n$. Therefore the basis of the free abelian group $C_n(X \times S^k)$ is
$$\mathcal B_n(X \times S^k) = \mathcal B_n(X)  \times \{b^0\} \cup \mathcal B_{n-k}(X)  \times \{b^k\} $$
where $\mathcal B_i(X)$ denotes the set of $i$-cells of $X$. Using the above boundary formula this shows that
$$C_n(X \times S^k) \approx C_n(X) \oplus C_{n-k}(X).$$
Since